# Generating HTML from XSL:FO using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

We are using XSL-FO to generate PDF in our project. What we would also like to do is to generate HTML from XSL-FO for user's preview. Is there any way to do this using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RenderX](http://www.renderx.com/) has, on their website, free XSLT stylesheets for a number of purposes, and one is for converting [XSL:FO to HTML](http://www.renderx.com/tools/fo2html.html).